# How do I set remove the database name from the query in Crystal Reports?

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

We are a development firm integrating Crystal Reports 2013 into our software. I need the ability to remove the database name from the SQL Query generated by Crystal Reports. We have customers running multiple instances of our software using the same data server. So we need to remove the database name so when it connects it uses the database specified in our file.dsn for an ODBC connection. We are using SQL Server as our data source. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you're using Crystal (this answer may or may not apply to your scenario).  If you're using the .Net objects (in VB or C#) and programming against them you can switch out your connection information programmatically.  It is finicky about the order in which you do it (e.g. you need to change the connection in the report and all sub reports, etc.).

I have two blog posts that have VB and C# with them that address changing database/connection dynamically through code, they are a few years old but they should still apply:

- http://www.blakepell.com/2012-05-22-crystal-reports-extension-methods
- http://www.blakepell.com/2010-09-17-crystal-reports-changing-the-database-connection-from-net-subreport-links-and-the-case-of-the-missing-parameter-values

On a side note, if you don't like the SQL that Crystal Reports generates you can always use a "Command" where you input your own SQL and then Crystal treats it kind of like a table (or you can take the SQL it generates to get your started and alter it to your liking, copy it, change it, then create a command with it).

Answer (score 0):

Crystal reports uses that query for generating the schema for the report which you can change the connection or change the query inside the code of software but the schema should be the same,

> perhaps you are not setting the connection of report by code successfully, you have to set the parameters and change the connection inside the code which loads the report if you do this successfully then you'll see the report.

Comment: We are doing this grammatically at this point, we were trying to do this with the designer and a file ODBC connection. Do you have any resources on how to to this programatically? Then can we open this in a viewer?

Comment: which language you are developing the software with?